# Revtex section heading alignment

Tags: sectioning, align, revtex

I am using `REVTex 4-1`, for my own personal use, not a paper submission. 
I like using `REVTex` and  I have gotten somewhat used to it, but for my current purposes I need left aligned subsections headings. In `REVTex` only `rmp` `documentclass` option gives that, but it also changes other aspects(I prefer `prb`).

I tried using command `\titleformat` from the `titlesec` package, but i can't figure out how to change only one option without changing other settings set by the `REVTex` (and `prb`)

```
\titleformat{\subsection}{\raggedright}{}{}{}

\titleformat*{\subsection}{\raggedright}
```

Is there a way to only set left alignment, without changing other settings?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply load the package `etoolbox` and patch the definitions of `\section` and `\subsection` to have `\raggedright` instead of `\centering`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[prb]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\section}
  {\centering}
  {\raggedright}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\subsection}
  {\centering}
  {\raggedright}
  {}
  {}


\begin{document}
\section{Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long section title}

\subsection{Long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long subsection title}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the `pra` option in document class and make the title move to the left, try this:

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
% move section headings to left
\titleformat{\section}{\raggedright\bfseries}{\arabic{section}.}{1em}{}`
```

Comment: (a) `\thesection` instead of `\arabic{section}` keeps the kind of numbering. (b) The corresponding command form of environment `flushleft` for left aligned text is `\raggedright`.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I cannot comply to your suggestion about replacing `\arabic{section}` though. In `revtex4-1` class roman numbering is set as default, and to dominate over this `\arabic{section}` seems to be the only possible way. Working with `\thesection` did not give the required result.

Comment: (a) I would not mix different numbering formats for the same entity. (b) If `\thesection` does not have the desired outcome, then it should be redefined.